# How to avoid Lucene from tokenizing query string containg '/' or '-'?

Tags: lucene

Good day!

In my document, I have a *date* field, which contains **ISO-8601** date, which can also be a period like *"25-08-2016/P1D"*

I want to search a document having exactly this date or period - so ,just having a same value of "date" field. Unfortunately, I was unable to do this. Tried different query strings, with escaping or without, like

- *date:"25-08-2016/P1D"* - is transformed to PhraseQuery, which fails with
  exception, AFAIUI since a field is just a String field
- *date:"25-08-2016/P1D"* - same as above
- *date:25-08-2016/P1D* -
  does not fail with exception, but still PhraseQuery is created, and
  nothing is being found
- *date:25-08-2016/P1D* - parsing fails with "org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 150.  Encountered:  after : "/P1D"

What I'm doing wrong? How can I tell Lucene to search this field using simple string match, without any tokenization?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've got, that escaping query string is a wrong way - correct way to achieve this is customizing Query analyzer for necessary field ("date" in my case).

```
Map<String, Analyzer> analyzerPerField = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>();
        analyzerPerField.put("date", new WhitespaceAnalyzer());
        analyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(
                    new StandardAnalyzer(), analyzerPerField);
        parser = new QueryParser("title", analyzer);
```

In given code, we just use *WhitespaceAnalyzer* (which is dividing query by whitespaces) instead of *SimpleAnalyzer* used by default, which is dividing text at non-letters. *WhitespaceAnalyzer* does not break ISO-8601 date.

For additional details about custom analyzing/tokenizing in lucene, please refer e.g. http://www.hascode.com/2014/07/lucene-by-example-specifying-analyzers-on-a-per-field-basis-and-writing-a-custom-analyzertokenizer/